# Angular 4 - Dependent value form selects

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have data structured like:

```
cars = [
    {name: 'Ferrari', models:['LaFerrari', 'Enzo', 'F40'],
    {name: 'Lamborghini', models:['Aventador', 'Diablo', 'Gallardo']
]
```

I'm using Angular Material for my form ui, which looks like:

```
<form [formGroup]="carsForm">
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="addChoice()">Add Car</button>
    <div formArrayName="carChoices">
      <div *ngFor="let choice of carChoices.controls; index as i">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Manufacturer" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" formControlName="manufacturer">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car">
              {{car.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="selectedValue">
          <mat-select placeholder="Model" formControlName="model">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let model of selectedValue.models" [value]="model">
            {{model}}
          </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here's the excerpt from my component class:

```
export class SelectFormExample {

    carsForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {this.initializeForm()}

    cars = [
      {name: 'Ferrari', models: ['LaFerrari', 'Enzo', 'F40']},
      {name: 'Lamborghini', models: ['Aventador', 'Diablo', 'Gallardo']}
    ];

    get carChoices() {
      return this.carsForm.get('carChoices') as FormArray;
    }

    initializeForm() {
      this.carsForm = this.fb.group({
        carChoices: this.fb.array([this.initializeChoices()])
      })
    }

    initializeChoices() {
      return this.fb.group({
        manufacturer: [''],
        model: ['']
      })
    }

    addChoice() {
      this.carChoices.insert(0, this.initializeChoices());
    }

}
```

How can I get model dropdown field to populate based on which car is selected?

I've tried using [(ngValue)] on the manufacturer mat-select field, but the problem with that is that there is an option on the form to add another car, and when another car is added it's automatically populated with the value from the previous selection.

EDIT: Here's a stackblitz showing what I'm trying to achieve - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9y72pr - the issue here is that I only need the car.name for my form model, and it doesn't work when more cars are added to the formGroup.

Here's a more complete stackblitz showing the issue when using multiple formGroups - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9y72pr-sjh8uh

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz app reproducing the problem? Or post the code in your component's class?

Comment: added a stackblitz, thanks.

Comment: Your options list for cars and models are referring to same list and value when you add a new one. This has to be independent.

Comment: I'm guessing I need to reference the formGroupName somewhere in the model select, but I'm not sure how.